# Cakephp 3 How to generate table schema from entities?

Tags: cakephp-3.0

I've a CakePHP 3 application and i want to generate the schema database from the existing models.
I'm new in Cakephp so i want to do a symfony look like command :

php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force

Thank you !

Comment: Do you mean you want to create tables based on existing cakephp model files? Or do you mean you want to create the cakephp model files from existing tables in your database?